# Pausing a popup video when clicking off of it

Tags: asp.net, video, popup

I'm trying to pause my popup video when I close the video.  But, I'm not sure how to do it.  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<a id="videoLinkButton" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0)" class="toplink" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';">
```

```
<div id="light" class="white_content">

<div style="padding: 66.67% 0 0 0; position: relative;">
    <iframe id="vimeoVideo" runat="server" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

Comment: See if the API for the Player is useful to you: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#methods-for-playback-controls

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.